# How to read JSON in data frame column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm reading a HDFS directory

```scala
val schema = spark.read.schema(schema).json("/HDFS path").schema

val df= spark.read.schema(schema).json ("/HDFS path")
```

Here selecting only PK and timestamp from JSON file

```scala
Val df2= df.select($"PK1",$"PK2",$"PK3" ,$"ts")
```

Then

Using windows function to get updated PK on the base of timestamp

```scala
val dfrank = df2.withColumn("rank",row_number().over(
        Window.partitionBy($"PK1",$"PK2",$"PK3" ).orderBy($"ts".desc))
    )
   .filter($"rank"===1)
```

From this window function getting only updated primary keys & timestamp of updated JSON.
Now I have to add one more column where I want to get only JSON with updated PK and Timestamp
How I can do that

Trying below but getting wrong JSON instead of updated JSON

```scala
val df3= dfrank.withColumn("JSON",lit(dfrank.toJSON.first()))
```

Result shown in image.

[image: output image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you convert the entire dataframe to JSON and collect it to the driver with `toJSON` (that's going to crash with a large dataframe) and add a column that contains a JSON version of the **first** row of the dataframe to your dataframe. I don't think this is what you want.

From what I understand, you have a dataframe and for each row, you want to create a JSON column that contains all of its columns. You could create a struct with all your columns and then use `to_json` like this:

```scala
val df3 = dfrank.withColumn("JSON", to_json(struct(df.columns.map(col) : _*)))
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for suggestions,but actually I want updated JSON from df as per your solution we are creating JSON of all columns of df

Comment: I am not sure to follow. Can you update your question with an example? Like what you have in input and what you expect in output?